# React component with Edit Mode and View Mode, is this a correct pattern?

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, jsx

I have a react component which displays a recipe. This component can be used to just view the data and also to edit the data, depending on a 'edit' prop being passed it.

At the moment I have some conditional logic which will hide/show certain elements depending on whether the user wants to edit or view the recipe. Here is my render function:

```
render() {
    let buttons = null;
    if (this.props.edit === 'true') {
        buttons = <div className="buttonList">
            <button onClick={this.onSave} className='defaultBtn'>Save</button>
            <button onClick={this.goBack} className='defaultBtn'>Discard Changes</button>
        </div>;
    } else {
        buttons = <div className="buttonList">
            <button onClick={this.goBack} className='defaultBtn'>Back</button>
        </div>;
    }
    return (
        <div className="single">
            <img src={this.state.recipe.imageURL} />
            <div className='recipeDetails'>
                <h1>{this.state.recipe.name}</h1>
                {this.props.edit === 'true' > 0 &&
                    <TextField type='text' floatingLabelText='Image URL' onChange={this.onImageUrlChange}></TextField>
                }
                <IngredientList onIngredientChange={this.onIngredientChange}
                    onDelete={this.onDelete}
                    ingredients={this.state.recipe.ingredients}
                    edit={this.props.edit}
                    addIngredient={this.addIngredient} />
                {buttons}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Is this the best way to achieve this? Using if statements like this feels wrong to me. I feel like I should have a ViewRecipe component and a EditRecipe component that share most of the code but have some logic to hide and show the relevant elements. Is there a certain React Pattern to do this? I've read a little about High Order Components but not sure if they fit this particular problem.

Am I overcomplicating this? 
Should I just have two separate components? 
Most of the logic on the Edit side of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your props naming needs review :

   `props.edit ='true'`  it can be `props.mode = 'edit' or 'view'`
2. mitigate the conditional logic (if...else)  of `render` method and break down it into methods prefixed by "render".
3. Solution will be :

   ```
     renderButtons() {
       if (this.props.mode === 'edit') 
         return (
           <div className="buttonList">
               <button onClick={this.onSave} className='defaultBtn'>Save</button>
               <button onClick={this.goBack} className='defaultBtn'>Discard Changes</button>
           </div>
         )
       else {
         return (
            <div className="buttonList">
               <button onClick={this.goBack} className='defaultBtn'>Back</button>
             </div>
          ) 
       }
     }

     renderTextField() {
       if (this.props.mode != 'edit') return null;
       return (
         <TextField type='text' floatingLabelText='Image URL' onChange={this.onImageUrlChange}></TextField>
       )
     }



     render() {

         return (
             <div className="single">
                 <img src={this.state.recipe.imageURL} />
                 <div className='recipeDetails'>
                     <h1>{this.state.recipe.name}</h1>
                     {this.renderTextField()}
                     <IngredientList onIngredientChange={this.onIngredientChange}
                         onDelete={this.onDelete}
                         ingredients={this.state.recipe.ingredients}
                         edit={this.props.edit}
                         addIngredient={this.addIngredient} />
                     {this.renderButtons()}
                 </div>
             </div>
         );
     }
   ```

Comment: That's one way to solve the problem given a simple component. The OP is asking whether this is the correct pattern or not which I don't think you've touched on.

Comment: Agreed, came here with the same question, this answer does not answer the question.

Comment: You are right @kevin_fitz. I wrote an answer in another question and I think it is relevant here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52904350/747579. You will love the answer.