# React conditionally rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple form build from React. Upon submission, if the error comes back, I wish to render an extra div to show error on the form.

Right now I got it to work but I do not like the solution. My solution is based on the knowledge that the component will only re-render if the state changes inside the render function (In this case this.state.errorMessages). So I had to explicitly put the if condition inside the render function like so

```
renderError() {
    var errArr = [];
    for (var key in this.state.errorMessages) {
        errArr = [...errArr, ...this.state.errorMessages[key]];
    }
    return (
        <div className="alert alert-danger">
            {errArr.map((err) => {
                return <p>{err}</p>
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

renderForm() {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleRegisterFormSubmit}>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label>First Name</label>
                <input type="text" className="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" value={this.state.firstName} onChange={this.handleFirstNameChange} required/>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" className="form-control" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" value={this.state.lastName} onChange={this.handleLastNameChange} required/>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label>Email address</label>
                <input type="email" className="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleEmailChange} />
                <small id="emailHelp" className="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" className="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handlePasswordChange}/>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label>Password Confirmation</label>
                <input type="password" className="form-control" name="password_confirmation" placeholder="Password Confirmation" value={this.state.passwordConfirmation} onChange={this.handlePasswordConfirmationChange}/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.handleCancelClick}>Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    )
}

render () {
    if (!this.state.errorMessages) {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.renderForm()}
            </div>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.renderForm()}
                {this.renderError()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I don't really like this approach as this could get nasty if I have more condition to re-render. I'm hoping there is a solution along the line of not having much logic in the actual render function and have that extracted out. For example...

```
renderError() {
    if (!this.state.errorMessages) {
        return;
    }
    var errArr = [];
    for (var key in this.state.errorMessages) {
        errArr = [...errArr, ...this.state.errorMessages[key]];
    }
    return (
        <div className="alert alert-danger">
            {errArr.map((err) => {
                return <p>{err}</p>
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

render () {
    <form onSubmit={this.handleRegisterFormSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input type="text" className="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" value={this.state.firstName} onChange={this.handleFirstNameChange} required/>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" className="form-control" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" value={this.state.lastName} onChange={this.handleLastNameChange} required/>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
            <label>Email address</label>
            <input type="email" className="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleEmailChange} />
            <small id="emailHelp" className="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" className="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handlePasswordChange}/>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
            <label>Password Confirmation</label>
            <input type="password" className="form-control" name="password_confirmation" placeholder="Password Confirmation" value={this.state.passwordConfirmation} onChange={this.handlePasswordConfirmationChange}/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.handleCancelClick}>Cancel</button>
        </div>
        {this.renderError}
    </form>
}
```

This throws an error because it complains that this.renderError should be called as a function. But when I put it as
this.renderError()
The error will never render because it does not get automatically called when errors come back.

-----------Update----------

Alternatively, why can't I do something like the following

```
render () {
    <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleRegisterFormSubmit}>
            ...
        </form>
        {if (this.state.errorMessages) {this.renderError()}}
    </div>
}
```

This throws console error

> Uncaught Error: Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token
> (117:13)

----------Update 2-----------

Essentially, I'm looking for a solution where inside the render function, I can easily show a whole block of code when the state changes. In Vue, I can do something like

```
<form>
    <input type="text">
</form>
<div v-if="hasError">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{something}}</div>
</div>
```

Can I do something as easy as this in React?

Comment: Put it as this.renderError() is correct. now you need to understand why it's not re-render. Probably because you're not using setState function to update the state. maybe you can share how you set the error message?

Comment: It's bad practice to put your logic in the render. If statements won't work inside your dom. Additionally, triggering this.renderError() does not make much sense here, as you just need to iterate over your errors. Please see my answer below.

Comment: What you could have done is a ternary condition. But if(this.state.errorMessages) might always be true if it's an empty object. Instead, use this `{Object.keys(this.state.errorMessages).length ? this.renderError() : null}` or `{Object.keys(this.state.errorMessages).length && this.renderError()}`

Comment: In that case above, its not really about whether I should use if or the ternary condition, it seems like react does not like having this sort of if statement inside {} inside render. Iv added comment to your answer below. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use map in order to extract the error message from your object.

Here below a minimal example of form validations and errors in React. It's good to understand how it works, but for my part, I use [Formik](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik#readme) which simplifies this process.

```
class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { errorMessages: {} };
    }

    handleRegisterFormSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault(); // don't submit the form until we run what's below
        let errorMessages = {};

        if (!this.state.lastName) errorMessages.lastName = 'You need to enter your last name';
        // And so on for each field validation

        // Do we have errors ?
        if (Object.keys(errorMessages).length > 0) {
            this.setState(errorMessages);
        } else {
            // Submit to server
        }
    };

    handleChange = e => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
            errorMessages: {
                ...this.state.errorMessages,
                [e.target.name]: null // remove the error of this field if it's being edited
            }
        });
    };

    render() {
        const errArr = Object.keys(this.state.errorMessages).map(key => this.state.errorMessages[key]);
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleRegisterFormSubmit}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" value={this.state.lastName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </div>

                {/* ... your dom */}

                <div>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                        Submit
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.handleCancelClick}>
                        Cancel
                    </button>
                </div>

                {errArr.length > 0 && (
                    <div className="alert alert-danger">
                      {errArr.map(err => {
                        return <p>{err}</p>;
                      })}
                    </div>
                )}
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

One more way to not display your alert div is with a ternary operator for your className and using bootstrap's `d-none`

```
<div className={errArr.length ? "alert alert-danger" : "d-none"}>
    {errArr.map(err => {
        return <p>{err}</p>;
    })}
</div>
```

Comment: Seems pretty close to what I want. However, you solution will mean that there will always be a div of alert alert-danger even when there is no error (not visible, but there). Is it possible to modify this so that this whole div will only be there when there is an error

Comment: Just edited. You can always wrap them in a logical operator [see this](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator)

Comment: Thanks for the upvote @user172902. Please mark as answer if you're satisfied with this answer, and happy coding. Ps: again, [Formik](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik) is really cool. Cheers

Comment: Thanks Asten. Was digesting and trying out your code. It works like a charm. Not quite the syntax that I'd expect but its relatively clean!

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is an architectural question.

Try to follow those practices:

1- Inject conditional statement inside JSX directly

2- Use functional components to render JSX not object methods

---

1- **Inject conditional statement inside JSX directly**

**Bad:**

```
if (!this.state.errorMessages) {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.renderForm()}
        </div>
    )
} else {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.renderForm()}
            {this.renderError()}
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Good:**

```
return <div>
            {this.renderForm()}
            {this.state.errorMessages && this.renderError()}
        </div>
```

**2- Use functional components to render JSX not object methods**

**Bad:**

```
class FormComponent {
  // ....

  renderError() {
    // Blah blah blah 
    return (
        <div className="alert alert-danger">
            {errArr.map((err) => {
                return <p>{err}</p>
            })}
        </div>
    )
   }

   render() {
     return (
       <div>
         <AnotherComponent />
         {this.renderError()}
      <div/>
     )
   }

}
```

then `{this.renderError()}`

**Good**

```
class FormComponent {
  // ....

   render() {
     return (
       <div>
         <AnotherComponent />
         {<Error />} {/* render it as componet ⚠️*/} 
      <div/>
     )
   }

}
// Build it as component outside the main component (FormComponent) ⚠️
function Error(props) { 
    return (
        <div className="alert alert-danger">
            {props.errArr.map((err) => {
                return <p>{err}</p>
            })}
        </div>
     )

 }
```

I spent many 2 years in React development of enterprise apps also graduating from Udacity and I am sharing my experience here. Congrats!

Answer (score 0):

One would usually render items in an element representing the list with some styling applied. We also sometimes don't want this wrapping element if we don't have any items.

I've written the following component which allows conditional rendering. When the condition is false, no elements are rendered keeping the DOM clean.

```
export default class If extends Component<{ condition: any }, {}> {

    render() {
        return this.props.condition ? this.props.children : <Fragment></Fragment>;
    }

}
```

One can now simply use the component as follow:

```
<If condition={items.length}>
    <-- item list -->
</If>
```