# Toggle style by clicking on button using styled-component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

After **onClick**, it starts function **onToggleLiked** in *app.js* which toggle **like** property and return(or not) **like** to *item.js*. After that, **AppListItem** check if **like** has appeared, and use styles from **const theme** if the result is *true*, else - from **defaultProps**.

How to do that? I've tried to create a function, but failed.

```
let AppListItem = styled.div`
.fa-heart {
          transform: ${props => props.theme.ts};
          opacity: ${props => props.theme.op};
      }`

AppListItem.defaultProps = {
   theme: {
    op: "0",
    ts: "translateX(30px)"
}}

const theme = {
    op: "1",
    ts: "translateX(0px)"
}
export default class PostListItem extends Component {
    render() {
           const {like} = this.props;
           if (like) {?}

return (
        <AppListItem>
            <ItemLabel as="span"
            onClick={onToggleLiked}>
                {label}
            </ItemLabel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply spread the desired properties, depending on the liked condition.

```
render() {
   const { like } = this.props;
   const props = like ? { theme: theme } : AppListItem.defaultProps;
   return <AppListitem {...props}>....;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant and works perfectly! But, what if I have multiple statements or multiple styles? Can you show me, how should it look like without ternary operator, please?

Comment: @AndrewKruglik Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65715555/6692685 and https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-pfurt?file=/index.js